# Why don't external hard drives have capacitors?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, clicking-sound

In Windows when you plug in some external hard drive there's like 90% chance you won't be able to unplug it safely. Half of the time you get the message that some program is using it even though it's not, and restarting the computer has no effect so you are forced to unplug it. The other half of the time it tells you it's safe to unplug it, but it's actually not because after you unplug it you hear that clicking sound. Macs don't have this issue. They always "eject" nicely without any clicking sounds.

Anyway, my question is, seeing that windows developers are incapable of fixing this hard drive killing windows bug, why don't hard drive manufacturers put a small capacitor in the hard drive so it has enough power after you unplug it to park that head safely?

Comment: Windows uses a different filesystem [NTFS] and method for mounting/unmounting than either BSD [Mac] or Linux, so the mounting and unmounting of drives is more straightforward [easier] in BSD/Linux than in Windows. Often Windows will refuse to eject a drive because of File Explorer itself, however once the OS has been rebooted, the drive can be unplugged anytime prior to BIOS/UEFI handing off to the Windows bootloader. As to capacitors, there are capacitors on the HDD's PCB whether you see them on the top or bottom layer of the PCB or not (capacitors can be on the internal layers too AFAIK).

Answer (score 3):

You are mistaken in your assumption that the problem is that you need to park the head safely. That has been solved decades ago in all harddisks (possibly with capacitors, but also possibly using the inertia of the rotating system). Actually most folks won't even remember that on early harddisks, you had do explicitely "park the head".

The reason you cannot unplug it safely is that for efficiency reasons, all OS keep part of the disk management data structures in memory. And these change often, so they don't get written out all of the time. And all OS (Mac, Windows, Linux) require some action from you so those get written.

And if you get the message that some program is using it, then some program is using it, even if you think it is not. So when you forcefully unplug it, you may have lost some data, because the disk management data structures have only been updated in memory, and have not been written out.

**Edit**

As pointed out in the comments, it's even more difficult with the write-cache that harddisks use: So even if the **OS cache** (which is in main memory, and that's why I used the term "memory") has already been written to the disk, the harddisk may still have data in its write cache that needs to be written back.

And I don't know which kind of clicking occurs for you. Clicking usually means that the drive recalibrates its head. The most likely reason this happens is that when you forcefully unplug the drive, you leave the filesystem in an invalid state, so on next boot or plugin, Windows tries to recover the filesystem, and put it into a good state. Which may involve reading sectors that are not read when the file system is in a good state to start with. And those sectors may be difficult to read, because they are degraded, which causes the clicking. One way to find out is to look at the SMART values for your disk, and/or figure out which sectors these are, and try to read them directly.

What definitely **is not** the reason is that the head wasn't parked properly because of "missing capacitors", that you had a headcrash and destroyed a part of your surface of the platters, and that now you get read errors because of that headcrash. And that the more often you do this, the more parts of your platter surface gets destroyed. Because **that** would read to **a lot** of more read errors.

Comment: I think this answer can be even better if you explain that write-cache means that a disk is still writing even though the OS already says the disk is ready. You have mentioned it, but used the term memory, rather than write-cache.

Comment: How do you explain that clicking always occurs on windows even when it says it's safe to remove, but not in mac os? And if they have capacitors why do they click?

Answer (score 2):

*Parking* isn't even the difficult part, head parking is achieved quite simply by having a magnet that pulls the head off the drive when power is removed. That's the easiest part to deal with. The difficult part is keeping the drive spinning and functioning to push data *onto* the disk.

A capacitor, or bank of them, capable of storing enough power to keep the drive spinning for several seconds while data is flushed from the cache and then allow the heads to be parked would probably be a significant amount of the current drive space.

It would have to have significant electronics to cope with a rapidly dissipating and decreasing supply voltage, at the same time as blocking any back-flow into the computer that would cause it to discharge faster.

And even then it wouldn't guarantee that the operating system *had* actually written all the relevant data to the disk. It does nothing to ensure data integrity at all. That is up to the operating system to do *before* power is lost, and the only way to make sure the operating system doesn't fall over when power is removed is to give the entire machine a battery.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 **Turn off write cache on the USB device.**

Next time you plug the external USB Hard disk in.

Open Device Manager

select **View devices by connection**

Find the USB and the Disk Drive(s) you wish to use.

Select it, then right click and choose **Properties**.

Open the **Policy** tab.

[x] Write-cache policy.

Uncheck the box to disable Disk Write Caching on this device.

Next, read the below item.

You can Turn off Windows write-cache buffer flushing on the device.

It might be best to restart the computer after you make this setting.

**Note** that this might not function on all USB hard disks.
You may only be able to set the radio boxes like **Quick Removal (default)**